# Kafka Producer/Consumer Unable to connect to localhost kafka cluster on server

Tags: apache-kafka

I Tried several links on Stackoverflow for solving this problem but I am unable to figure out this problem for the last couple of hours.

Basically I have setup Apache Kafka on my office server using this link [Kafka Setup Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-18-04)

The services have been created and they both are running.

This is the Command that I am using in order to execute it

> After cd into the Kafka Bin Directory ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TutorialTopic --from-beginning

But while running the consumer as mentioned in the example,It throws me the following error

> WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Here is a Screenshot of my server.properties file
[image: Kafka Server.properties]

I also tried to change the localhost in the command to 127.0.0.1 still i got the same error

I have mentioned the localhost ip explicitly since I thought it might work as by default it was not working.

The same setup in currently working in my local env but not on the server.
Appreciate any help on this topic

Comment: where are you running your consumer from? the same machine as Kafka or different?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt From the same machine via a different terminal.

Comment: did you try changing IP to localhost? Also  can you check /etc/hosts file and make sure you have entry for 127.0.0.1 pointing to localhost ?

Comment: @user3817206 I did check the /etc/hosts file and in that I do have an entry for localhost

Comment: is this fixed ?

Comment: No @user3817206